# In elasticsearch, how to group results by location proximity?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a bunch of documents with a location field, and for a given search query with given coordinates, I would like to group results by whether their location is within 25 miles of the given coordinates. However within each group I would like the results sorted not by location proximity. Is there any elegant way to do this?

As an example, imagine I have the following documents:

```
[
  { id: "1", price: 13.5, coords: $c1 },
  { id: "2", price: 10, coords: $c2 },
  { id: "3", price: 15, coords: $c3 },
  { id: "4", price: 5, coords: $c4 },
  { id: "5", price: 1, coords: $c5 },
]
```

where $c1, $c2, $c3 are within 25 miles of $c, and $c4, $c5 are farther than 25 miles from $c. The order by proximity to $c is $c3, $c2, $c1, $c5, $c4. When handling a query of sorting by price low to high, I would like to return as

```
[
  [
    { id: "2", price: 10, coords: $c2 },
    { id: "1", price: 13.5, coords: $c1 },
    { id: "3", price: 15, coords: $c3 },
  ],
  [
    { id: "5", price: 1, coords: $c5 },
    { id: "4", price: 5, coords: $c4 },
  ]
]
```

Comment: it might help if you post some an example doc and any queries you have tried to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To group results in this way, you could use aggregations (or facets pre-1.0) - specifically the geo distance aggregation. This will give you a count of the number of results in each group ( <= 25 miles, > 25 miles). Then, to retrieve the hits within each group, use a geo distance filter together with your original query.

On the sorting, you should be able to use something like

```
{
    "sort" : [
        { "price" : {"order" : "asc"}}
    ],
    "query" : {
        ...
    }
}
```

To achieve this in a single API call, you could try the multi-search API. This is the _msearch endpoint and would take something like the following:

```
GET _msearch
{}
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "price": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance_range" : {
            "from" : "0mi",
            "to" : "25mi"
            "pin.location" : {
                "lat" : $c_lat,
                "lon" : $c_long
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
{}
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "price": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance_range" : {
            "from" : "25mi"
            "pin.location" : {
                "lat" : $c_lat,
                "lon" : $c_long
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Take note of the empty headers ({}) preceding each query. I used Sense to test this out and had a few problems with parsing failures - use Ctrl+I to un-indent the JSON before sending.

This returns an array of responses, one per query - each response is equivalent to the result of using the corresponding query with the Search API.

If your use case is to always display all of the results, the second approach would be appropriate and fulfils the requirement for a single API call. However, if you want to display the result groups individually, the first approach could be more efficient, as you would not be retrieving unused results.

If this solution doesn't do what you need, please add a bit more detail to the question and I'll think again!

Links:

- Geo distance aggregation: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/search-aggregations-bucket-geodistance-aggregation.html
- Geo distance filter:
  http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-filter.html
- Sorting: 
  http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html
- Function score:
  http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html
- Multi-search API: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html

Comment: I added an example to the question. Ideally I would want to do this in a single call to elasticsearch if possible. Otherwise, I could always just search by a filter of <= 25 miles first, and when the result goes to the last page, do another query by a filter of > 25 miles, which is a less elegant solution.

Comment: You could make use of the multi search API (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html)

This will allow you to do both searches in a single call.

Comment: Thanks @Akshay - good find! I've tested that out and updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you! Just wondering, could this be integrated nicely with pagination?

Comment: Interesting question! Pagination is normally handled by the "from" and "size" parameters in a query (defaulting to 0 and 10 respectively) - and hence requires multiple API calls again. If your goal really is to try to do this in a single call, the pagination would have to be handled on the client side (and make sure the size parameter is set high enough on the two queries to get both full sets of results in that single call).