# Prioritise match results by geo_point and ordering by closest location in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a `GET` request, that is matching query string. It is searching within address strings and now returns solid and relevant results from an index.

Now I'd like to **prioritise** results by distance, so first, relevant strings are returned and **ordered** by **closest geo_point parameter**.

Putting the `sort` into the same level, right after the `query` parameter actually does not return hits sorted by distance. It returns weird results and it is definitely not what I want.

This is the **mapping** I use:

```
{
   "location": {
      "properties": {
         "address": {
            "type": "string"
         },
         "gps": {
            "type": "geo_point"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The request I am doing now is:

**GET** */locations/location/_search*

```
{        
   "query": {
       "match" : {
            "address" : {
                "query": "Churchill Av"                               
            }
        }      
   },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_geo_distance": {
        "gps": { 
          "lat": 51.358599, 
          "lon": 0.531964
        },
        "order":         "asc",
        "unit":          "km", 
        "distance_type": "plane" 
      }
    }
  ]   
}
```

I know that the best way would be gettting the results by match first and then sorting those few results by distance, so the geo-distance calculation is not too expensive.

I tried [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096659/in-elasticsearch-how-to-group-results-by-location-proximity), but it didn't help.

EDIT: I need to mention, that I store geo_point data in my index like this:

```
"_source": {
    "address" : "Abcdef, ghijk, lmnoprst"
    "gps": [
        51.50,
        1.25
    ]
}
```

QUESTION: How to set the the geo distance sorting / filter, so results are sorted **after** the match query, ordered by closest geo_point parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

I realised that as the **geo_point** data is stored as an **indexed array** and that means the values are as `[Lon, Lat]`, and not `[Lat, Lon]` as I expected, it is **unable to search within** _geo_distance pattern of **associative array**:

```
{
    "lat" : Lat,
    "lon" : Long
}
```

From elasticsearch.co Docs:

> Please note that string geo-points are ordered as lat,lon, while array
>   geo-points are ordered as the reverse: lon,lat.

So **the correct sort notation in this manner is**

```
"_geo_distance": {
    "gps": [51.358599,0.531964],                      
}
```

OR

```
"_geo_distance": {            
    "gps": {
        "lat": 0.531964,
        "lon": 51.358599  
     }  
}
```

... because I store my geo_point data as [LON, LAT] and not [LAT, LON], as I had thought.

Now it work as expected. My problem is now, that I should reindex data with reverse order of latitude/longitude within the geo_point array.

I hope this remark could help someone else.